# table (\tabular + \shortstack) gives weird result

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am using a [template](http://www.degruyter.com/view/supplement/s20814836_LaTeX_Template.zip) from this [journal](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pjbr). When I am placing table in covering 2 columns (textwidth) using `table*` I get the following error.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[USenglish,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%(only for the pdftex engine)

\usepackage[big]{dgruyter_author}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\articletype{Research Article{\hfill}Open Access}
\author*[1]{Corresponding Author}
\affil[1]{Affil, E-mail: email@email.edu}
\title{\huge Article title}
\runningtitle{Article title}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

\subsection{2D v.s. 3D VSL}

\begin{table*}[h!t]
\caption{The main differences between the 2D and 3D VSL approach.}
\label{table:differences}
%\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
 & \textbf{2D VSL}                                                                                                                                  & \textbf{3D VSL}                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
Source of information   & 2D Image     & 3D Point Cloud    \\ \hline
Applicable for  & 3DOF Reconfiguration (X, Y, $\theta$)  & 6DOF Reconfiguration (X, Y, Z, $\theta$, $\phi$, $\gamma$) \\ \hline
Transformation matrix   & 2D to 2D (3x3)  & 3D to 3D (4x4) \\ \hline

{\shortstack{ Estimating the observations \\ in demonstration phase }} &
{\shortstack{ Background Subtraction \\ Thresholding}} &
{\shortstack{ Voxelizing \\ Kd-tree \\ K Nearest-Neighbor search }} \\ \hline

{\shortstack{Match finding in\\ reproduction phase}}                 & {\shortstack{2D Features\\ 2D Feature Estimation\\ 2D Metrics (SIFT)\\ RANSAC for finding the rotation}}       & {\shortstack{3D Features\\ 3D Feature Estimation\\ Voxelizing\\ Normal/Curvature Estimation\\ 3D Metrics (ICP/RANSAC/SAC-IA)}}           \\ \hline
Main assumptions                                                                                   & {\shortstack{No overlap among objects\\ Objects have the same height \\ Objects are placed at the same level}} & {\shortstack{Applicable for partially visible objects\\ Objects can have different heights\\ Objects can be placed in different levels}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

The problems are:

1- the table doesn't fill the whole textwidth
2- the borderlines are not connected at some places
3- there are extra lines

P.S. before using `\shortstack` I was using `\tabular` but there was a `\noalign` error, which I suspected is because of the style of the template. The table using the IEEE style is OK with no problem.

Comment: Did you try the `makecell` package, that allows for common formatting of cells and linebreaks inside cells with the `thead`, `makecell`, `\multirowthead`  and `\multirowcell` commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dgruyter_author` package redefines `tabular` so that it basically uses `booktabs` commands without user's intervention. As such, vertical rules shouldn't be used.

For the split cells you can use a stack:

```
\documentclass[USenglish,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%(only for the pdftex engine)

\usepackage[big]{dgruyter_author}

\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\Centerstack{#1}}

\begin{document}
\articletype{Research Article{\hfill}Open Access}
\author*[1]{Corresponding Author}
\affil[1]{Affil, E-mail: email@email.edu}
\title{\huge Article title}
\runningtitle{Article title}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

\subsection{2D v.s. 3D VSL}

\begin{table*}[h!t]
\caption{The main differences between the 2D and 3D VSL approach.}
\label{table:differences}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\hline
 & \textbf{2D VSL} \\ \hline
Source of information   & 2D Image     & 3D Point Cloud    \\ \hline
Applicable for  & 3DOF Reconfiguration (X, Y, $\theta$)  &
   6DOF Reconfiguration (X, Y, Z, $\theta$, $\phi$, $\gamma$) \\ \hline
Transformation matrix   & 2D to 2D (3x3)  & 3D to 3D (4x4) \\ \hline

\splitcell{Estimating the observations \\ in demonstration phase} &
  \splitcell{Background Subtraction \\ Thresholding} &
  \splitcell{Voxelizing \\ Kd-tree \\ K Nearest-Neighbor search} \\ \hline

\splitcell{Match finding in\\ reproduction phase} &
  \splitcell{2D Features\\ 2D Feature Estimation\\ 2D Metrics (SIFT)\\
             RANSAC for finding the rotation} &
  \splitcell{3D Features\\ 3D Feature Estimation\\ Voxelizing\\
             Normal/Curvature Estimation\\ 3D Metrics (ICP/RANSAC/SAC-IA)} \\ \hline
Main assumptions &
  \splitcell{No overlap among objects\\ Objects have the same height \\
             Objects are placed at the same level} &
  \splitcell{Applicable for partially visible objects\\
             Objects can have different heights\\
             Objects can be placed in different levels} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use another package, the following definition of `\splitcell` will work too

```
\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \begin{baretabulars}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\strut#1\strut\end{tabular}%
  \end{baretabulars}%
}
```

[image]

---

### Note

There is a bug in `dgruyter_author.sty`: the conditional initiated on line 953 is not properly ended. So between the current lines 954 and 955 a line containing

```
\fi
```

should be inserted. The current code is

```
953 \ifx\dgf@nts\@undefined
954   \RequirePackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
955 \newbox\dg@wordmark
```

(line numbers added for clarity); it should be

```
\ifx\dgf@nts\@undefined
  \RequirePackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
\fi
\newbox\dg@wordmark
```